# Merge many data as one data

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have data like this

```
 CCSKIYEARDOULE     |    CCSKIYEAR
 ------------------------------------ 
 92-93              |     92 
 92-93              |     93
 94-95              |     94
 94-95              |     95
 96-97              |     97
```

But I want the output like this

```
 CCSKIYEARDOULE     |    CCSKIYEAR
 ------------------------------------ 
 92-93              |     92, 93
 94-95              |     94, 95
 96-97              |     97
```

I already use the group_concat, but I got an error "ORA-00904: "GROUP_CONCAT": invalid identifier"

This is my code

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CCSKIYEARDOUBLE), CCSKIYEAR FROM CCS2_TBL_KI2 GROUP BY CCSKIYEARDOUBLE ORDER BY CCSKIYEAR ASC;
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` function only exists in MySQL/MariaDB. You can use `MODEL` in Oracle as described in [this article](https://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/).

Comment: You have to use `LISTAGG` function. Read https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030 Works of Oracle 11g+. If you have older versions, u could use some of the techniques discussed here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Answer (score 1):

```
Below check below query 

create table CCSK
 (CCSKIYEARDOULE varchar2(10),
 CCSKIYEAR number);

 begin
 insert into CCSK values ('92-93',92);
 insert into CCSK values ('92-93',93);
 insert into CCSK values ('94-95',94);
 insert into CCSK values ('94-95',95);
 insert into CCSK values ('96-97',97);
end;



 select CCSKIYEARDOULE,listagg(CCSKIYEAR,',')
 from CCSK
 group by CCSKIYEARDOULE;
```

Comment: `WITHIN` keyword is required  in Oracle 11g. This might have worked for you in Live sql(18c) or 12c ( I'm not sure),  but  definitely not in 11g

Comment: Yes , I have checked only in live sql